# Is this injective in this case?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've known the fact (1) for the  $f : X \to Y$

(1) $f$ is injective $\iff$  $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for all $A,B(\subset X)$.

I have proved the below (2) for the function $f : X \to Y$

(2) $\forall X_1 \subset X$, $Y_1 \subset Y$ then $f(X_1 \cap f^{-1}(Y_1)) = f(X_1) \cap Y_1$

So my question is regarding the (2) the function $f$ is injective or not.

If not, what is the difference between the (1) and (2) ?

Considering the $\forall X_1 \subset X$, it looks like a injective in my thought, But I can't prove it

Comment: For one thing, $f^{-1}(Y_1)$ is not necessarily equivalent to "any $B\subset X$".

Comment: @DavidP, Err..  I missed that point

Comment: also $f^{-1}(Y_1)$ can be empty

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi, Yes it definitely could be.

Comment: without $Y_1$ being empty

Comment: What did you prove? That $(2)$ holds for injective functions $f$?

Comment: Please, choose carefully the tags. This question is not about topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what exacty you have proved concerning $(2)$. Anyway, let us show that $(2)$ is true for **each** function $f : X \to Y$.

1. Let $y \in f(X_1 \cap f^{-1}(Y_1))$. There exists $x \in X_1 \cap f^{-1}(Y_1)$ such that $f(x) = y$. Since $x \in f^{-1}(Y_1)$, we have $y = f(x) \in Y_1$, thus $y \in  f(X_1) \cap Y_1$.
2. Let $y \in  f(X_1) \cap Y_1$. Since $y \in f(X_1)$, there exists $x \in X_1$ such that $f(x) = y$. In other words, $x \in f^{-1}(y) \subset f^{-1}(Y_1)$ because $y \in Y_1$. Thus $x \in  X_1 \cap f^{-1}(Y_1)$ and this implies $y = f(x) \in f(X_1 \cap f^{-1}(Y_1))$.